# Is there a limit to the value levels in a proc format statement?

Tags: sas

proc format; 
    value $STNAME   'AL'='Alabama'
                    'AK'='Alaska
                    'AR'='Arkansas'
                    'AZ'='Arizona'
                    'CA'='California'
                    'CO'='Colorado'
                    'CT'='Connecticut'
                    'DC'='DistrictOfColumbia'
                    'DE'='Deleware'
                    'FL'='Florida'
                    'GA'='Georgia'
                    'HI'='Hawaii'
                    'IA'='Iowa'
                    'ID'='Idaho'
                    'IL'='Illinois'
                    'IN'='Indiana'
                    'KS'='Kansas'
                    'KY'='Knetucky'
                    'LA'='Louisiana'
                    'MA'='Massachusetts'
                    'MD'='Maryland'
                    'ME'='Maine'
                    'MI'='Michigan'
                    'MN'='Minnesota'
                    'MO'='Missouri'
                    'MS'='Mississippi'
                    'MT'='Montana'
                    'NC'='North Carolina'
                    'ND'='North Dakota'
                    'NE'='Nebraska'
                    'NH'='New Hampshire'
                    'NJ'='New Jersey'
                    'NM'='New Mexico'
                    'NY'='New York'
                    'NV'='Nevada'
                    'OH'='Ohio'
                    'OK'='Oklahoma'
                    'OR'='Oregon'
                    'PA'='Pennsylvania'
                    'RI'='Rhode Island'
                    'SC'='South Carolina'
                    'SD'='South Dakota'
                    'TN'='Tennessee'
                    'TX'='Texas'
                    'UT'='Utah'
                    'VA'='Virginia'
                    'VT'='Vermont'
                    'WA'='Washington'
                    'WI'='Wisconsin'
                    'WV'='West Virginia'
                    'WY'='Wyoming';
run;

It freezes up in the middle of the proc format step. If I split I shorten it, it runs fine.
Anyone aware how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your hard drive can hold the SAS program file, it does not have a limit on the number of unique values inside a proc format or the amount of memory needed to load it. As @Carolina has suggested you are missing an end quote for Alaska. If there is no end quote, the states after Alaska are in a different color. After you add the end quote, the highlighting after Alaska should change to a unanimous color.

Like this:
[screenshot link](http://puu.sh/5kdqy.png)

It might be better to use more conventional spacing for better readability.
Also, you might want spaces between 'DistrictOfColumbia' and Kentucky is spelt incorrectly. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing quote on Alaska. I placed the code in my IDE and I could tell from the highlighting.